# Regex for repeated pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I have ran out of both Stackoverflow and Google for this!

Anyway, I want to delete the repetition in the below string, and replace it with

```
import re

s = '''
Heey yeah all the waay from heere 
'''
def re_show(pat, s): 
    print(re.compile(pat, re.M).sub("{\g<0>}", s.rstrip()))


print(re_show(r"(\w)(\w)\2(\w*)", s))
```

Current output  `{Heey} yeah {all} the {waay} from {heere}`

Expected output `H{ee}y yeah a{ll} the w{aa}y from h{ee}re.`

I think my re_show is checking letters before the repeated letter, but when I try

```
print(re_show(r"(\w)\2", s))
```

I am getting an error.

As you probably guessed, Regex is not my strongest topic, the opposite in fact.

Comment: Sorry - edited, forgot to correct code

Comment: How should `{abcc}` be treated? `{abbdd}`? `{abbcdd}`?

Comment: ...and `{aa}`, `{aaa}` and `{aaaa}`?

Comment: You've seen my questions. Please answer them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are, don't bother you to capture the letters around the repetition, what you need is a larger group to enclose all the repetition letters

```
def re_show(pat, s):
    print(re.compile(pat, re.M).sub(r"{\g<1>}", s.strip()))

re_show(r"((\w)(\2))", s)
```

Comment: If I run your code with `s = '{Heey} yeah {all} the {wxaay} from {heere} or {eeere} or {xyaaa} or {aaa}'` I get `{H{ee}y} yeah {a{ll}} the {wx{aa}y} from {h{ee}re} or {{ee}ere} or {xy{aa}a} or {{aa}a}`. [Demo](http://tpcg.io/0kvIStx8). Can you explain? (Perhaps I made a mistake.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland because you never told that it could be more than 2 repetition so the code is not for it, so it can be more than 2 repetitions ?

Comment: I see what you mean, but if `s = {heere}` , your code returns `{h{ee}re}`, whereas `h{ee}re` is wanted. No? [Demo](http://tpcg.io/96ffwcin)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ow just see you're the post owner^^ so your requirement are just not the same. the code is supposed to ADD bracket arround 2 repetition letter, not removing the actual ones

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression

```
r"{(.*?)(?=(.)\2)(\2+)(.*?)}"
```

replacing matches with

```
r"\1{\3}\4"
```

```
import re

str = "{Heey} yeah {all} the {wxaay} from {heere} or {eeere} or {xyaaa} or {aaa}"
print re.sub(r"{(.*?)(?!=(.)\1)(.)(\3+)(.*?)}",
  r"\1{\3}\4", str)
  #=> "H{ee}y yeah a{ll} the wx{aa}y from h{ee}re or {eee}re or xy{aaa} or {aaa}"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BwWpOJ/4/)

[Python demo](http://tpcg.io/0kvIStx8)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
{          # match '{'
(.*?)      # match 0+ chars in cap grp 1
(?=(.)\2)  # match is followed by two equal chars
           # (.) being cap grp 2
(\2+)      # match cap grp 2 1+ times, save to cap grp 3
(.*?)      # match 0+ chars, save to cap grp 4
}          # match '}'
```

`(?=(.)\2)` is a *positive lookahead*.

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern you use `(\w)(\w)\2(\w*)` which will match at least 3 chars using 3 capturing groups and `\g<0>` will contain all that is matched.

In the replacement you use `{\g<0>}` which is the whole match surrounded by curly braces which can give you `{heere}` for example.

---

You could use a single capturing group followed by a backreference `(\w)\1` and omit the `re.M` as there are no anchors in the pattern. You could also use a single print statement.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/QxD9aN)

*Example code*

```
import re

s = '''
Heey yeah all the waay from heere 
'''
def re_show(pat, s): 
    print(re.compile(pat).sub("{\g<0>}", s.rstrip()))

re_show(r"(\w)\1", s)
```

*Ouput*

```
H{ee}y yeah a{ll} the w{aa}y from h{ee}re
```